# Remove Save/New Button from a custom page

Tags: button-overrides

I have cloned a standard page into a custom page.  How do I remove the Save/New button from my custom page?  Do I need to go into Developer Console...or???

Comment: Have you created a visualforce page or Is it new Page Layout for Object?

Comment: It's a custom object and I cloned the standard page layout for it.  I can't remove the Save/New button from the original layout, and am hoping to be able to do so in the cloned edition.

Comment: could you include a screenshot of the exact button you mean? I don't have a Save/New button on my standard page layout..

Comment: Guy, it appears on edit pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can not able to remove Save and New button from standard page layout.

Here is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrXMAA0) on IdeaExchange for the same.

One way is to override New button with Custom visual force page and only the required button. But this involves a custom code.

[Override Standard Buttons](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_customize_override.htm)

Create a Visualforce Page and Override it with a New Button.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.site}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.type}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.accountNumber}"/>

        <!-- Add all required fields -->
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Check [Using Standard Controller Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm)

Comment: Devendra,  How is this done?

Comment: Devandra,  How do I edit the new component and identify the id of the button?

Comment: I thought on adding a custom component to hide button, but I think that would not be ideal solution as it involves capturing the class/id of button and this css is under Salesforce control. SO, tweaking their css wont be good idea. Instead you can override the new Button with Custom visualforce page and on that VF page just show Save and Cancel button.

Comment: I agree with your idea of editing the button in a custom VF page.  I don't know how to copy my cloned standard page into the VF page so I can see the code.

Comment: Thanks for the override code.  How can I view my cloned page in VF so I don't have to re-create the page in VF from scratch?

Comment: You need to create new VF page from Setup--> Visualforce Pages. Earlier you created a custom page layout. Here you need to create new VF page. Page layouts and VF pages are two separate functionalities.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to copy the code of the Page layout to a VF page.  I was trying to avoid replicating the code.  Thanks.